# It seems that Proxool caused a dead loop

Tags: java, multithreading, proxool

Today I have an app, which used near 100% CPU resource. I made some thread dumps. Found that:

```
"resin-port-8080-284" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00002ad370261000 nid=0x79c5 runnable [0x00002ad30b32d000]
    java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.util.HashMap.getEntry(HashMap.java:465)
    at java.util.HashMap.get(HashMap.java:417)
    at org.logicalcobwebs.proxool.proxy.InvokerFacade.getConcreteMethod(InvokerFacade.java:38)
    at org.logicalcobwebs.proxool.WrappedConnection.invoke(WrappedConnection.java:111)
    at org.logicalcobwebs.proxool.WrappedConnection.intercept(WrappedConnection.java:87)
    at $java.lang.AutoCloseable$$EnhancerByProxool$$66bad385.getWarnings(<generated>)
    at org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter.logAndClearWarnings(JDBCExceptionReporter.java:45)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.closeConnection(ConnectionManager.java:472)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.cleanup(ConnectionManager.java:408)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.close(ConnectionManager.java:347)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.close(SessionImpl.java:335)
```

The linked list in HashMap should have a cyclic chain, so the CPUs keep running and consumed all resources.

Proxool version is 0.9.0RC3 and Java is 1.7.

So I do not why it happen? Most of time the app is ok. And from the source code, the related Proxool classes seem to be thread-safe.

Is it Proxool's bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [InvokerFacade](https://github.com/proxool/proxool/blob/master/src/java/org/logicalcobwebs/proxool/proxy/InvokerFacade.java) class has a static HashMap and mutates it without synchronization.

The HashMap [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) clearly states:

> If multiple threads access a hash map concurrently, and at least one
>   of the threads modifies the map structurally, it must be synchronized
>   externally

This is a defect and can lead to all sorts of strange behavior, including what you are observing here.

[Explain the timing causing HashMap.put() to execute an infinite loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13695832/explain-the-timing-causing-hashmap-put-to-execute-an-infinite-loop)

[Infinite loop in java.util.HashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10219724/infinite-loop-in-java-util-hashmap)

Comment: Yes, just look at `InvokerFacade` code, it is not thread safe. But I am not sure whether classes which use `InvokerFacade` have fully protections for the concurrent access.

Comment: The evidence indicates they do not. Indeed, by using a static variable, it makes it impractical to externally synchronize.